# Android Firebase UI change default error messages

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I want to customize this error message shown in screenshot. I am unable to find any options when creating `Intent` using `AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()`.

[image]

This error is reproducible. All you have to do is go to Firebase Auth screen, disconnect device from internet, and try signing in using Google.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a feature request for Firebase UI.  It should be posted to that project's GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-android

Comment: So I currently I cannot change this message?

Comment: No, you can't..